I can't get my string to display properly
So basically, the below code should display the following. "This text variable1 then this text variable2 followed by this text"
textBox1.Text = string.Format("This text {0} then this text {1} followed by this text", variable1, variable2);

This instead display the following "This text variable1 variable2 then this text followed by this text"

I cannot see how that would happen, and having tested your code, it does work correctly. I suspect there is some other code that you have not shown us.

The code you posted is unlikely to produce the result you mentioned (unless variable1 is the string "variable1 variable2" and variable2 is an empty string). Please post a [mre].

I cannot see how two variables could be squeezed into one placeholder. Something else must be going on.
Does variable1 contain all the text that was supposed to be split among variable1 and variable2?

String interpolation can make things easier and you can't confuse the indices:
textBox1.Text = $"This text {variable1} then this text {variable2} followed by this text";

You would use String.Format only if the format was supplied as a variable. If it is supplied as a string literal, use string interpolation.

Stupidly enough, I accidentally put all of the information in variable1. Both variables are 2 different lists joined together, but I accidentally put all of the information in only one of the lists!

String interpolation will not solve the OP's problem if the content of the variables is wrong, but nevertheless it is a good and useful recommendation. +1.

One reason I do choose String.Format over string interpolation sometimes is when one or more of the parameters is used multiple times. It can make things a little more succinct, especially if the expressions used as parameters are long. String.Format also allows you to put each parameter on a different line, possibly making the code a little more readable.
